# Is the verify() line needed in the cordapp-tutorial code?

Tags: corda

Just wondering, I've noted that in the CollectSignaturesFlow there's this call:

```
partiallySignedTx.tx.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub).verify()
```

And in the ExampleFlow there's this line:

```
txBuilder.toWireTransaction().toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub).verify()
```

Is it needed in both places? Don't they call the same routine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right - these checks duplicate one another. In this case, we've left it in as an example of good practice - not everyone is looking at the definition of `CollectSignaturesFlow`!

However, you might want to verify the transaction before signing as part of a try/catch block, and modify the transaction if verification fails (however, this isn't what we do here).

Please also note that:

`partiallySignedTx.tx.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub).verify()`

Can actually be replaced by:

`partiallySignedTx.verify(serviceHub)`